# finding full stops in google sheet cell strings, excluding file extensions eg .xlsx

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im attempting to migrate from Google Drive to Microsoft OneDrive and the migration continually fails due to invalid characters such as `~ " # % & * : < > ? / \ { | }`.

I've removed all instances of the above characters from the files/folders and it is still failing.
I believe it is due to full stops in the middle of file/folder names an example is below:

`Acuse.GASP8409257P9.6.2021.pdf`

Basically I would want to find all instances of full stops in the middle of the file names, while excluding just files that have file extensions such as .docx

Would a regex do the job here? I've attempted to find one online, but to no avail, any help is appreciated.

I've attempted to use a regex to find the full stops but nothing is working as I would like.

Comment: Just for further clarification, what you would want to happen is to create a script to automatically rename all files within Google Drive that has full stops in the middle of the file/folder names, is that correct?

Comment: Also, if you could provide a sample expected output on your post to further clarify this, what would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
*(following [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76181624/finding-full-stops-in-google-sheet-cell-strings-excluding-file-extensions-eg-x/76188581?noredirect=1#comment134377042_76188581)): "...how to replace the full stops with underscores _ instead"*

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\D+$|[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]",""),".","_")
                 &REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\D+$")
```

result: `Acuse_GASP8409257P9_6_2021.pdf`

---

**Original reply**

Please try the following

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(\W)|(.\D+$)","$2")
```

**OR**

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\D+$|\W","")
      &REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\D+$")
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: That answer above works great, thanks. Last thing I would like to know, is how to replace the full stops with underscores _ instead?

Comment: Please see the updated reply.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed, replace dots with underscores!